# Conditionals thowing error in DB2 query using partition and sum with case

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm trying to perform a few calculations as conditionals for my query (the query as a whole is based on 90 days but I want some calculations that only take the last 30 days into account as well as conditional groupings)

but my below query throws an error that there is ```an unexpected '(' expecting FROM,INTO

Here's the query:

```
SELECT
  employee,
  manager,
  productGroup,
  productDetail,
  productCategory,
  productCount,
  quant as sales,

  /*problem starts below*/
  sum(case when last_date > current_date - 30 days then quant else 0 end) over (partition by employee) as emp_25,
  sum(case when last_date > current_date - 30 days then quant else 0 end) over (partition by manager) as manager_25,
  sum(case when last_date > current_date - 30 days then quant else 0 end) over (partition by p.productGroup) as productGroup_25

FROM PRODUCTS p
WHERE last_date > CURRENT_DATE - 90 days
ORDER BY manager,productGroup,productDetail,productCategory;
```

Basically I get the itemized count but I want the last 3 'SUM' values to return the sum of quantity for the product group listed grouped by the employee, the manager, and then total for the last 30 days

Is my syntax just incorrect?

Comment: syntax looks fine to me. What DB2 platform/version are you using? If it is very very old, if might not support OLAP functions

Comment: DB2 for iseries 7.2, and I don't believe it supportst them. It breaks at the partition no matter what

Comment: Did you check in the manual to see if they are supported? It looks like they are to me https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzolapexp.htm

Comment: Ah no, I'm wrong. I'll answer below

Comment: Side note: dates should normally be queried lower-bound inclusive, especially if timestamps are involved (for instance, if `last_date` was a timestamp, you'd be excluding any events that occurred at midnight).

Answer (score 1):

Db2 for iSeries 7.2 only supports ranking and row numbering in it's implementation of OLAP (aka windowing) expressions.

E.g. contrast this manual page for Db2 for i 7.2

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/db2/rbafzolapexp.htm

against this page for Db2 11.1 (for LUW) which allows column aggregation functions in OLAP expressions

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0023461.html